# Git rebase - commit select in fork-point mode

Tags: git, github, version-control

Reading the `git rebase` and `git merge-base` man documentation:

> After working on the topic branch created with git checkout -b topic origin/master, the history of remote-tracking branch origin/master may have been rewound and rebuilt, leading to a history of this
>   shape:
>
> ```
>                         o---B1
>                        /
>        ---o---o---B2--o---o---o---B (origin/master)
>                \
>                 B3
>                  \
>                   Derived (topic)
> ```
>
> where origin/master used to point at commits B3, B2, B1 and now it points at B, and your topic branch was started on top of it back when origin/master was at B3. This mode uses the reflog of
>          origin/master to find B3 as the fork point, so that the topic can be rebased on top of the updated origin/master by:
>
> ```
> $ fork_point=$(git merge-base --fork-point origin/master topic)
> $ git rebase --onto origin/master $fork_point topic
> ```

`$fork_point` will ( if I understand it correctly ) be the commit object `B3`, and, thus the commits `B3..topic` will be rebased onto to `origin/master` branch.

**Q1** Why is it useful to omit the `B3` commit? The commits of the `topic` branch are built on top of the `B3` commit, so omitting it would mean that its modifications would then be missing in the story of the `origin/master` branch. Rebasing the `B3` commit *and* the `topic` branch would lead to a cleaner history, wouldn't it?

**Q2** Can someone link / briefly describe practical use cases of the `--fork-point` option in the git workflow?

Comment: With Git 2.24 (Q4 2019), you can also consider [`git rebase --keep-base <upstream>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58252582/6309).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are correct that `$fork_point` will be `B3`.

I *believe* the intent here is to omit `B3` as "not your commit".

I think the diagram the Git folks drew here is not so good.  Here's how I would redraw and rewrite it without changing it too much (though I'd probably just re-letter each commit anyway).

---

You begin by cloning (or otherwise updating to) some (`origin`) repository whose graph ends in commit `B3`, and you create a topic branch and make some commit(s):

```
...--o---F---B3    <-- origin/master
              \
               G   <-- topic
```

Over time, with additional `git fetch`-es and `git commit`s, your commit graph now looks like this:

```
...--o---F---B3--B2--B1    <-- origin/master
              \
               G---H---I   <-- topic
```

But, suddenly, after *another* `git fetch`, your own commit graph now looks like this:

```
                 o---B1'       <-- origin/foo
                /
...o---F---B2'-o---o---o---B   <-- origin/master
        \
         B3--G---H---I         <-- topic
```

That is, Git would now think that commit B3 belongs on your topic branch, when in fact, *your* work begins with commit `G`.  The people who own the repository named `origin` have, in effect, declared that commit `B3` is terrible and should be thrown away.  (They kept a copy of `B2` as `B2'` on their `master`, and one of `B1` as `B1'` on their `foo`.)

If you simply `git rebase`, you will copy original commit `B3` to new copy `B3'` (while also copying `G-H-I`):

```
                 o---B1'                     <-- origin/foo
                /
...o---F---B2'-o---o---o---B                 <-- origin/master
                            \
                             B3'-G'--H'--I'  <-- topic
```

but you would instead prefer:

```
                 o---B1'                 <-- origin/foo
                /
...o---F---B2'-o---o---o---B             <-- origin/master
                            \
                             G'--H'--I   <-- topic
```

For `git rebase` to do this, you must instruct Git to locate commit `B3`.  Your reflog for `origin/master` has all of `F`, `B3`, `B2`, and `B1` in it (under at least one reflog entry, including in this case `origin/master@{1}`), while your own `topic` has `F` and `B3`, but not `B2` nor `B1`, in it as well.  Therefore `--fork-point` chooses `B3` as the newest (tip-most) shared commit, rather than `F`.

---

The key sentence / idea in here is that the upstream repository writers *intended to discard commit `B3` entirely*.

(How you are supposed to know this for certain is a bit of a mystery.  It may not be obvious that `B2'` and `B1'` are copies, if the rebasing required, e.g., discarding a file that should never have been committed—and was in `B1`, which is why `B1` was also discarded.  The fact that this file is now omitted in `B2'` and `B3'` makes them not-patch-equivalent, hence not obviously copies.)

(Note that your own `master` also still points to `B3`!)

Comment: Is there ever any user case for `--fork-point` if the upstream branch does not change history? Every example I've seen describes a situation where upstream has modified the history (e.g. rebase, amend or filter-branch) while you were working with your topic branch.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen: I think not: if the upstream always grows without shedding previous commits, fork-point should never do anything. It should not *break* anything either in this case, though.

Comment: If I am right, this can only happen when someone forced push master into remote repo for graph to change suddenly like this in 3rd figure of answer ?

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin: Yes, and it's pretty clear that `--fork-point` is *intended* to address upstream force-push. I don't think it's a great implementation, but there is no single correct behavior here. Mercurial's Evolve extension is in theory a much better way to deal with this (how it works in practice I don't know, not having used it) but Evolve does not fit well into Git's implementation.

Answer (score 0):

My answer doesn't address original questions but provides some guidance how to recover and do a proper rebase in case where B3 is considered to be a part of topic branch (should be rebased and not dropped).

First of all, let's assume bad rebase has just completed and we need to revert from it. We can do this with following command:

```
$ git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD
```

Now we want to fix our fork-point rebase. Let's find bad fork-point:

```
$ git merge-base --fork-point origin/master topic
<B3-full-hash>
```

or in short form:

```
$ git rev-parse --short $(git merge-base --fork-point origin/master topic)
<B3-short-hash>
```

Now let's find undesired reflog entries for upstream branch:

```
$ git reflog show origin/master | grep <B3-short-hash>
<B3-short-hash> ... origin/master@{3}: ...
<B3-short-hash> ... origin/master@{7}: ...
...
```

There can be multiple reflog entries referring to bad fork point. Now we should delete them. From lowest to highest in the list:

```
...
$ git reflog delete origin/master@{7}
$ git reflog delete origin/master@{3}
```

Once done `--fork-point` will no longer able to find bad fork points. And we could re-run our rebase again:

```
$ git rebase --fork-point origin/master
```

As shown it's not that trivial to do and still requires a lot of care. Hence probably it could be easier just to find proper base/upstream on history and run `git rebase --onto=origin/master HEAD~2`.