# git pull --rebase lost commits after coworker's git push --force

Tags: git, version-control, rebase

I thought I understood how git pull --rebase was working, but this example is confusing me. I would have guessed that the following two scenarios would produce identical results, but they differ.

First, the one that works.

```
# Dan and Brian start out at the same spot:
dan$ git rev-parse HEAD
067ab5e29670208e654c7cb00abf3de40ddcc556

brian$ git rev-parse HEAD
067ab5e29670208e654c7cb00abf3de40ddcc556

# Separately, each makes a commit (different files, no conflict)
dan$ echo 'bagels' >> favorite_foods.txt
dan$ git commit -am "Add bagels to favorite_foods.txt"

brian$ echo 'root beer' >> favorite_beverages.txt
brian$ git commit -am "I love root beer"

# Brian pushes first, then Dan runs `git pull --rebase`
brian$ git push

dan$ git pull --rebase
dan$ git log
commit 9e1140410af8f2c06f0188f2da16335ff3a6d04c
Author: Daniel
Date:   Wed Mar 1 09:31:41 2017 -0600

    Add bagels to favorite_foods.txt

commit 2f25b9a25923bc608b7fba3b4e66de9e97738763
Author: Brian
Date:   Wed Mar 1 09:47:09 2017 -0600

    I love root beer

commit 067ab5e29670208e654c7cb00abf3de40ddcc556
Author: Brian
Date:   Wed Mar 1 09:27:09 2017 -0600

    Shared history
```

So that works out fine. In the other scenario, imagine that Dan pushed, and then Brian (rudely) push --force'd over his commit. Now, when Dan runs `git pull --rebase`, his commit is gone.

```
# Dan and Brian start out at the same spot:
dan$ git rev-parse HEAD
067ab5e29670208e654c7cb00abf3de40ddcc556

brian$ git rev-parse HEAD
067ab5e29670208e654c7cb00abf3de40ddcc556

# Separately, each makes a commit (different files, no conflict)
dan$ echo 'bagels' >> favorite_foods.txt
dan$ git commit -am "Add bagels to favorite_foods.txt"

brian$ echo 'root beer' >> favorite_beverages.txt
brian$ git commit -am "I love root beer"

# THIS TIME, Dan pushes first, then Brian force pushes.
dan$ git push

brian$ git push --force

dan$ git pull --rebase
dan$ git log  # Notice, Dan's commit is gone!
commit 2f25b9a25923bc608b7fba3b4e66de9e97738763
Author: Brian
Date:   Wed Mar 1 09:47:09 2017 -0600

    I love root beer

commit 067ab5e29670208e654c7cb00abf3de40ddcc556
Author: Brian
Date:   Wed Mar 1 09:27:09 2017 -0600

    Shared history
```

The origin version of the branch had the same state after Brian's `push --force` as it did in the first scenario, so I expected the same behavior from `git pull --rebase`. I'm confused why Dan' commit was lost.

I understand pull --rebase to say "take my local changes, and apply them after the remote ones". I don't expect the local changes to be thrown away. Also, If Dan had run `git pull` (with no `--rebase`), his commit is not lost.

So why does Dan lose his local commit when he runs `git pull --rebase`? The force push makes sense to me, but shouldn't that just leave the remote in the same state as if Brian had pushed first?

How am I thinking about this wrong?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

#### TL;DR: it's the fork point code

You are getting the effect of `git rebase --fork-point`, which deliberately drops Dan's commit from *your* repository too.  See also [Git rebase - commit select in fork-point mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42486141/1256452) (although in my answer there I don't mention something I will here).

If you run the `git rebase` yourself, you *choose* whether `--fork-point` is used.  The `--fork-point` option is used when:

- you run `git rebase` with no `<upstream>` argument (the `--fork-point` is implied), or
- you run `git rebase --fork-point [<arguments>] <upstream>`.

This means that to rebase on your upstream *without* having `--fork-point` applied, you should use:

```
git rebase @{u}
```

or:

```
git rebase --no-fork-point
```

Some details are Git-version-dependent, as `--fork-point` became an option only in Git version 2.0 (but was secretly done by `git pull` ever since 1.6.4.1, with methods growing more complex until the whole `--fork-point` thing was invented).

## Discussion

As you already know, `git push --force` rudely overwrites the branch pointer, dropping some existing commit(s).  You expected, though, that your `git pull --rebase` would *restore* the dropped commit, since you already had it yourself.  For naming convenience, let's use your naming, where Dan's commit gets dropped when Brian force-pushes.  (As a mnemonic, let's say "Dan got Dropped".)

Sometimes it will!  Sometimes, as long as your Git has Dan's commit in *your* repository, and you have Dan's commit in *your* history, Dan's commit will get restored when you rebase your commits.  This includes the case where you *are* Dan.  And yet, sometimes it won't, and this *also* include the case where you are Dan.  In other words, it's not based on *who you are* at all.

The complete answer is a bit complicated, and it's worth noting that this behavior is something you can control.

#### About `git pull` (don't use it)

First, let's make a brief note: `git pull` is, in essence, just `git fetch` followed by either `git merge` or `git rebase`.<sup>1</sup>  You choose in advance which command to run, by supplying `--rebase` or setting a configuration entry, `branch.branch-name.rebase`.  However, you can run `git fetch` yourself, and then run `git merge` or `git rebase` yourself, and if you do it this way, you gain access to additional options.<sup>2</sup>

**The most important of these is the ability to *inspect the result of the fetch* before choosing your primary option** (merge vs rebase).  In other words, this gives you a chance to *see* that there was a commit dropped.  If you had done a `git fetch` earlier and gotten Dan's commit, then—with or without any intervening work where you may or may not have incorporated Dan's commit—done a second `git fetch`, you would see something like this:

```
 + 5122532...6f1308f pu         -> origin/pu  (forced update)
```

Note the "(forced update)" annotation: this is what tells you that Dan got Dropped.  (The branch name used here is `pu`, which is one in the Git repo for Git that regularly gets force-updated; I just cut-and-pasted an actual `git fetch` output here.)

---

<sup>1</sup>There are several niggling technical differences, especially in very old versions of Git (before 1.8.4).  There is also, as I was recently reminded, one other special case, for a `git pull` in a repository that has no commits on the current branch (typically, into a new empty repository): here `git pull` invokes neither `git merge` *nor* `git rebase`, but rather runs `git read-tree -m` and, if that succeeds, sets the branch name itself.

<sup>2</sup>I think you can supply all the necessary arguments on the command line, but that's not what I mean.  In particular, the ability to run *other* Git commands *between* the fetch and the second step is what we want.

#### Basics of `git rebase`

The main and most fundamental thing to know about `git rebase` is that it *copies* commits.  The *why* is itself fundamental to Git: nothing—no one, and not Git itself—can *change anything* in a commit (or any other Git object), as the "true name" of a Git object is a cryptographic hash of its contents.<sup>3</sup>  Hence if you take a commit out of the database, modify *anything*—even a single bit—and go to put the object back in, you get a new, different hash: a *new and different* commit.  It can be extremely similar to the original, but if any bit of it is different in any way, it's a new, different commit.

To see how these copies work, draw at least part of the commit *graph*.  The graph is just a series of commits, starting from the newest—or *tip*—commit, whose true-name hash ID is stored in the branch's name.  We say that the name *points to* the commit:

```
            D   <-- master
```

The commit, which I've called `D` here, contains (as part of its hashed commit data) the hash ID of its *parent* commit, i.e., the commit that *was* the tip of the branch before we made `D`.  So it "points to" its parent, and its parent points further back:

```
... <- C <- D   <-- master
```

The fact that the internal arrows are all backwards like this is usually not very important, so I tend to omit them here.  When the one-letter names are not very important I just draw a round dot for each commit:

```
...--o--o   <-- branch
```

For `branch` to "branch off from" `master`, we should draw both branches:

```
A--B--C--D     <-- master
    \
     E--F--G   <-- branch
```

Note that commit `E` points back to commit `B`.

Now, if we want to *re-base* `branch`, so that it comes after commit `D` (which is now the tip of `master`), we need to *copy* commit `E` to a new commit `E'` that is "just as good as" `C`, except that it has `D` as its parent (and of course has a different snapshot as its source base as well):

```
           E'  <-- (temporary)
          /
A--B--C--D     <-- master
    \
     E--F--G   <-- branch
```

We must now repeat this with `F` and `G`, and when we are all done, make the name `branch` point to the last copy, `G'`, abandoning the original chain in favor of the new one:

```
           E'-F'-G'  <-- branch
          /
A--B--C--D           <-- master
    \
     E--F--G         [abandoned]
```

This is what `git rebase` is all about: we pick out some set of commits to copy; we copy them to some new position, one at a time, in parent-first order (vs the more typical child-first backwards Git order); and then we re-point the branch *label* to the last-copied commit.

Note that this works even for the null case.  If the name `branch` points directly to `B` and we rebase it on `master`, we copy all zero commits that come after `B`, copying them to come after `D`.  Then re-point the label `branch` to the last-copied commit, which is none, which means we re-point `branch` to commit `D`.  It's perfectly normal, in Git, to have several branch names all pointing to the same commit.  Git knows which branch you are on by reading `.git/HEAD`, which contains the *name of the branch*.  The branch itself—some portion of the commit graph—is determined by the *graph*.  This means the word "branch" is ambiguous: see [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)

Note also that commit `A` has no parents at all.  It's the *first* commit in the repository: there was no previous commit.  Commit `A` is therefore a *root* commit, which is just a fancy way to say "a commit with no parents".  We can also have commits with two or more parents; these are *merge commits*.  (I did not draw any here, though.  It's often unwise to rebase branch chains that contain merges, since it's literally impossible to rebase a merge and `git rebase` has to re-*perform* the merge to approximate it.  Normally `git rebase` just omits merges entirely, which causes other problems.)

---

<sup>3</sup>Obviously, by the [Pigeonhole Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), any hash that reduces a longer bit-string to a fixed-length *k*-bit key must necessarily have collisions on some inputs.  A key requirement for a Git hash function is that it avoid accidental collisions.  The "cryptographic" part is not really crucial to Git, it just makes it hard ([but of course not impossible](https://shattered.it/)) for someone to *deliberately* cause a collision.  Collisions cause Git to be unable to add new objects, so they are bad, but—aside from bugs in the implementation—they don't actually break Git itself, just the further usage of Git for your own data.

---

#### Determining what to copy

One problem with rebasing lies in identifying *which commits to copy*.

Most of the time, it seems easy enough: you want Git to copy *your* commits, and not someone else's.  But that's not always true—in large, distributed environments, with administrators and managers and so on, sometimes it's appropriate for someone to rebase someone else's commits.  In any case, this is not how Git does it in the first place.  Instead, Git uses the graph.

Naming a commit—e.g., writing `branch`—tends to select not just *that* commit, but also that commit's parent commit, the parent's parent, and so on, all the way back to the root commit.  (If there is a merge commit, we usually select *all* of its parent commits, and follow all of them back towards the root simultaneously.  A graph can have more than one root, so this lets us select multiple strands going back to multiple roots, as well as branch-and-merge strands going back to a single root.)  We call the set of all commits that we find, when starting from one commit and doing these parent traversals, the *set of reachable commits*.

For many purposes, including `git rebase`, we need to make this en-masse selection *stop*, and we use Git's fancy set operations to do that.  If we write `master..branch` as a revision selector, this means: "All commits reachable from the tip of *branch*, except for any commits reachable from the tip of *master*."  Look at this graph again:

```
A--B--C--D     <-- master
    \
     E--F--G   <-- branch
```

The commits reachable from `branch` are `G`, `F`, `E`, `B`, and `A`.  The commits reachable from `master` are `D`, `C`, `B`, and `A`.  So `master..branch` means: subtract away the A+B+C+D set from the bigger A+B+E+F+G set.

In set subtraction, removing something that was never there in the first place is trivial: you just do nothing.  So we remove A+B from the second set, leaving E+F+G.  Alternatively, I like to use a method that I can't draw on StackOverflow: color the commits red (stop) and green (go), following all the backwards arrows in your graph, starting with red for commits that are forbidden (`master`) and green for commits to take (`branch`).  Just make sure that red *overwrites* green, or that you do red first and don't re-color them when you're doing green.  It's intuitively obvious<sup>4</sup> that doing green first, then overwriting with red; or doing red first and *not* overwriting, gives the same result.

Anyway, this is one way `git rebase` selects commits to copy.  The rebase documentation calls this the `<upstream>`.  You write:

```
git checkout branch; git rebase master
```

and Git knows to color `master` commits red and current-branch `branch` commits green, and then copy just the green ones.  Moreover, that same name—`master`—tells `git rebase` where to put the copies.  This is quite elegant and efficient: a single argument, `master`, tells Git both *what to copy* and *where to put the copies*.

The problem is, it doesn't always work.

There are several common cases where it breaks down.  One occurs when you want to limit the copies even more, e.g., to break up one big branch into two smaller ones.  Another occurs when some, but not all, of your own commits have already been copied (cherry-picked or squash-"merged") into another branch you're rebasing onto.  Rarer, but not unheard-of, sometimes an upstream has deliberately discarded some commits, and you should too.

For some of these cases, `git rebase` can deal with them using [`git patch-id`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-patch-id.html): it can actually tell that a commit got copied, as long as the two commits have the same patch ID.  For others, you must manually split the rebase *target* (rebase calls this `<newbase>`) using the `--onto` flag:

```
git rebase --onto <newbase> <upstream>
```

which limits the commits to copy to those in `<upstream>..HEAD`, while starting the copies after `<target>`.  This—splitting the targeting of the copies away from the `<upstream>` argument—means that you are now free to choose any `<upstream>` that removes the *right* commits, rather than some set determined by "where the copies go".

---

<sup>4</sup>This is the phrase mathematicians use when they don't want to write out a proof. :-)

---

#### The `--fork-point` option

If you regularly rebase commits onto an `origin/whatever` branch (or similar) that is, itself, *also* regularly rebased specifically with a goal of *removing* commits, it can be hard to decide which commits to copy.  But if you have, in your `origin/whatever` *reflog*, a series of commit hashes that show that some commits *were* there before but are no longer, it's possible for Git to use this to discard, from the to-copy set, some or all of those commits.

I was not entirely sure how `--fork-point` is implemented internally (it's not very well documented).  For [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42493771/1256452), I made a test repository.  The option was, unsurprisingly, order-dependent: `git merge-base --fork-point origin/master topic` returns a different result from `git merge-base --fork-point topic origin/master`.

For this answer, I looked at the [source code](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/merge-base.c#L148).  This shows that Git looks in the reflog of the *first* non-option argument—call this `arg1`—and then uses it to find a merge base using the *next* such argument `arg2` resolved to a commit ID, completely ignoring any additional arguments.  Based on this, the result of `git merge-base --fork-point $arg1 $arg2` is essentially<sup>5</sup> the output of:

```
git merge-base $arg2 $(git log -g --format=%H $arg1)
```

As [the documentation says](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge-base.html):

> More generally, among the two commits to compute the merge base from, one is specified by the first commit argument on the command line; the other commit is a (possibly hypothetical) commit that is a merge across all the remaining commits on the command line.
>
> As a consequence, the *merge base* is not necessarily contained in each of the commit arguments if more than two commits are specified. This is different from [git-show-branch(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show-branch.html) when used with the `--merge-base` option.

So `--fork-point` tries to find the merge base between the current hash for the second argument, and the hypothetical merge base of the current value of the upstream *and* all of its reflog-recorded values.  This is what leads to the exclusion of a dropped commit, such as the one by Dan in our example here.

Remember, using `--fork-point` mode merely modifies, internally, the `<upstream>` argument to `git rebase` (without also changing its `--onto` target).  Let's say, for instance, that at one time, the upstream had:

```
...--o--B1--B2--B3--C--D    <-- upstream
                 \
                  E--F--G   <-- branch
```

The goal, as it were, of `--fork-point` is to detect a rewrite of this form:

```
...--o-------------C--D     <-- upstream
      \
       B1--B2--B3           <-- upstream@{1}
                \
                 E--F--G    <-- branch
```

and "knock out" commits `B1`, `B2`, and `B3` by selecting `B3` as the internal `<upstream>` argument.  If you *leave out* the `--fork-point` option, Git views everything this way instead:

```
...--o-------------C--D     <-- upstream
      \
       B1--B2--B3--E--F--G  <-- branch
```

so that all the `B` commits are "ours".  The commits on the upstream branch are `D`, `C`, and `C`'s parent `o` (and its parents, on to the root).

In our particular case, Dan's commit—the one that gets dropped—resembles one of these `B` commits.  It's dropped with `--fork-point` and kept with `--no-fork-point`.

---

<sup>5</sup>If, were one to use `--all`, this would produce *multiple* merge bases, the command fails, and prints nothing.  If the resulting (singular) merge base is not a commit that is already in the reflog, the command also fails.  The first case occurs with criss-cross merges as the nearest ancestor.  The second case occurs when the selected ancestor is old enough to have expired from the reflog, or was never in it in the first place (I am pretty sure both are possible).  I have an example of this second kind of failure right here:

```
$ arg1=origin/next
$ arg2=stash-exp
$ git merge-base --all $arg2 $(git log -g --format=%H $arg1)
3313b78c145ba9212272b5318c111cde12bfef4a
$ git merge-base --fork-point $arg1 $arg2
$ echo $?
1
```

I *think* the idea of skipping `3313b78...` here is that it is one of those "possibly hypothetical commits" I quote from the documentation, but in fact it would be the right commit to use with `git rebase`, and it's the one that *is* used *without* `--fork-point`.

---

#### Git before 2.0, and conclusion

In Git versions before 2.0 (or maybe a late 1.9), `git pull` that was rebasing would compute this fork point, but `git rebase` never did.  This meant that if you *wanted* this kind of behavior, you *had* to use `git pull` to get it.  Now that `git rebase` has `--fork-point`, you can choose when to get it:

- Add the option if you definitely *do* want it.
- Use `--no-fork-point` or an explicit upstream (`@{u}` suffices if you have a default upstream) if you definitely *don't* want it.

If you run `git pull`, you do not have the `--no-fork-point` option.<sup>6</sup>  <s>Whether `git pull origin master` (assuming the current branch's upstream is `origin/master`) suppresses the fork-point the way `git rebase origin/master` would, I do not know: I mostly avoid `git pull`.</s>  According to testing (see [Breaking Benjamin's comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42536989/git-pull-rebase-lost-commits-after-coworkers-git-push-force/42546368?noredirect=1#comment95801543_42546368)), in Git 2.0+, `git pull --rebase` always uses fork-point mode, even with additional arguments.

---

<sup>6</sup>At least, as of now when I just tested it to make sure.

Comment: May you please explain when case 2 with two upstreams (from `The --fork-point option` section) occur? If we have example 1 then parent of `C` is `B3`, is not? How "knock out" commits are detected?

Comment: @EugenKonkov you can't have two upstreams: `--fork-point` looks at *one* reflog, that reflog being the one for whatever reference you gave. You could do two separate `git rebase` operations, with two separate references, but that's still just one upstream (at a time).

Comment: Yes, of course, but how "knock out" commits are detected? If I understand right, with `--fork-point` `B1` `B2` `B3` are counted as `theirs`. How this detection works?

Comment: @EugenKonkov What `--fork-point` does is dig through the reflog. Say, for instance, you ask about the "fork point" of a commit with hash ID *H* vs reference name *R*. The reflog for *R* lists some set of hash IDs *R1* through *Rn* and the fork-point is the commit before (or including) *H* that is after the latest (least ancestor-y) of the various *Ri*s that are an ancestor of *H*.

Comment: @torek I confirm that `git pull --rebase origin master` does not suppress fork-point. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54464216/understanding-git-pull-rebase). I have tested it in git 2.18.

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin: right, OK: Git 2.0+, `pull --rebase` always uses the fork-point code. Pre-2.0, some `git pull --rebase` operations used something similar to the fork-point code, and some `git pull --rebase` operations didn't. `git rebase` itself *never* used the fork-point code until it existed as a separate `git merge-base --fork-point` option, which it does in 2.0+. So in 2.0+, some `git rebase`s use the fork-point code and some don't, depending on arguments. I've updated the final part of the above answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the solution:

```
git reflog
```

Dig through there to find the lost commit SHA.  then...

```
git cherry-pick <SHA-of-the-commit-you-found>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the scenarios are not confusing, that's how `push --force` works.

I will not explain the first scenario because you also understand that. But in the second scenario when `brian$ git push --force` this happens, brian's local repository doesn't know anything about dan's push to the remote.

So it take brian's local copy & replace everything there in the remote because it's a `force push`.

The difference between `git pull` & `git pull --rebase` is,

`git pull` will compare the changes of origin & local. That's why even you have uncommited changes you can `git pull`.

`git pull --rebase` will not compare the changes with the local, but it takes everything from the origin. That's why you can't `git pull --rebase` if there are uncommited changes

Hope you understand what I said.
Any questions??

Comment: Hmm, I understand `pull --rebase` to say "take my local changes, and apply them *after* the remote ones". I don't expect the local changes to be thrown away. I'll edit the question to include this detail.

Comment: In your case it will not apply your local changes on top of the remote once because you already pushed your local changes & because someone else force push, your local repo lost the tracking for your remote.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this looks right. Brian's `git push --force` is going to set the latest commit as the one he has on his local system. If Brian had first pulled any latest commits and then `git push --force` the results would be the same.

Here is a good thread with more info: [Force "git push" to overwrite remote files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510462/force-git-push-to-overwrite-remote-files)

Comment: So why does Dan lose his local commit when he runs `git pull --rebase`? The force push makes sense to me, but shouldn't that just leave the remote in the same state as if Brian had pushed first? I'll add this thought to the original question.

Comment: Because `git push --force` rewrites the commit history.

Comment: It rewrites the commit history of the _remote_. I don't expect it to rewrite the commit history of everyone's local clone.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your understanding of `git pull --rebase` is correct.

It’s because the commit `9e11404` has pushed to remote, while after that, the commit `2f25b9a` is force update the remote (`9e11404` if force removed from remote).

When Dan execute `git pull --rebase`, git detected `9e11404` and origin/branch is point to `2f25b9a`. But git think `9e11404` has already exist in remote (`.git\logs\refs\remotes\origin\branch` has the content `update by push 9e1140410af8f2c06f0188f2da16335ff3a6d04c`), so it do nothing to rebase. Or you can use `git pull --rebase=interactive` to verify, you will find it shows `noop` to rebase. If you want to manually rebase `9e11404` on the top of origin/branch, you can add `pick 9e11404` in interactive window, The result will be what you expected.