# why git force update my commit during git push --mirror?

Tags: git

I got an issue on git and asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49164906/why-git-pull-rebase-results-a-forced-update) before, not resolved.

When I execute `git push --mirror` on my own git server, during its running, I push a commit to my git server, it accepted.

```
➜  ljmall git:(master) ✗ gp
Counting objects: 4, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 1.06 KiB | 1.06 MiB/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git.dmright.com:/opt/git/ljmall
   a436fdda3..88ceb916e  master -> master
```

After `git push --mirror` is done, I think I should push again because there should be one new commit on git server, but it told me `Everything up-to-date`

```
dejavu@ljhost-01:/opt/git/ljmall.git$ sudo -H -u git git push --mirror
Everything up-to-date
```

Then I run `git pull --rebase` on my development machine, my last commit is forced update.

```
Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: 88ceb916e feat: resources
From git.dmright.com:/opt/git/ljmall
 + 88ceb916e...a436fdda3 master     -> origin/master  (forced update)
```

Comment: It's a designed behavior of `--mirror`, described in the manual of `git push`.

Comment: but it removed my commit on git server instead of on mirror server, if I commit to the mirror server, it is removed after git push --mirror, it makes sense.