# Why fork-point is updated?

Tags: git

I did some commits on branch `MyCurrent`. Then realize that I do them on another and leave current branch untouched.

Thus I create new branch at root point (where I should start new branch):

```
git checkout -b fixes 6735ff2
```

And check the root of branch:

```
$ git merge-base --fork-point fixes
6735ff23c52338fbaafbfa1707f0bcbb1e5b9698
```

Then I merge (maybe I should cherry-pick?) the current branch

```
$ git merge --ff-only MyCurrent
Updating 6735ff2..e1700a5
Fast-forward
...
```

When I check `form-point` again - it is moved:

```
git merge-base --fork-point fixes
e1700a59dd
```

Why fork point is updated?

Comment: Incidentally, it occurs to me that you might think `git merge-base --fork-point` is intended to find the point at which the current branch forked from some parent branch. It's not—it does not do that at all, and *cannot* do it as branches don't record their parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git merge-base --fork-point` uses the reflog:

> For this answer, I looked at the [source code](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/merge-base.c#L148).  This shows that Git looks in the reflog of the first non-option argument—call this arg1—and then uses it to find a merge base using the next such argument arg2 resolved to a commit ID, completely ignoring any additional arguments.  Based on this, the result of `git merge-base --fork-point $arg1 $arg2` is essentially<sup>5</sup> the output of:
>
> ```
> git merge-base $arg2 $(git log -g --format=%H $arg1)
> ```

Since `git merge --ff-only MyCurrent` updated the reflog, adding a new commit hash, it's unsurprising that the `--fork-point` value would change.  (Note that `arg2` here defaults to `HEAD`, since you did not give one.)

(Note: the footnote explains where these results differ, along with an example.  It's not literally exactly the same.)

See my (rather long) answer to [git pull --rebase lost commits after coworker's git push --force](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42536989/1256452) (scroll down to the section labeled "The `--fork-point` option") for more.

Comment: You have said that branch does not store info about the point it forked from. But how then `git log --graph --oneline` knows the point where branch is started?

Comment: That's only true in simple cases. Suppose branch B is created at commit S (for start), then one makes N commits on B, then one merges B into M, then one makes more commits on B, and so on. Now, it is possible to read *this* graph and guess where the start was; but consider [Chris Johnsen's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3162929/1256452): Where did these branches start?