# Understanding git pull --rebase

Tags: git

I learned that `git pull --rebase origin master` = `git fetch origin master` + `git rebase origin/master`. I am using **git 2.18**

But when I read [this blog](http://gitolite.com/git-pull--rebase) , It says it is not always the case.

*(Please correct me from here if I understood something wrong)*

The blog gives an example to show the different behaviour of `git pull --rebase` as otherwise we all know.

He says ,

> Let's say your starting point is this:
>
> `a---b---c---d---e  (origin/foo) (also your local "foo")`
>
> Time passes, and you have made some commits on top of your own "foo":
>
> `a---b---c---d---e---p---q---r (foo)`
>
> Meanwhile, in a fit of anti-social rage, the upstream maintainer has not > only rebased his "foo", he even used a squash or two. His commit chain now looks like this:
>
> `a---b+c---d+e---f  (origin/foo)`
>
> A git pull at this point would result
>   in chaos. Even a `git fetch; git rebase origin/foo` would not cut it,
>   because commits "b" and "c" on one side, and commit "b+c" on the
>   other, would conflict. (And similarly with d, e, and d+e).
>
> What `git pull --rebase` does, in this case, is:
>
> `git fetch origin git rebase --onto origin/foo e foo`
>
> This gives you:
>
> `a---b+c---d+e---f---p---q---r (foo)`
>
> You may still get conflicts, but
>   they will be genuine conflicts (between p/q/r and a/b+c/d+e/f), and
>   not conflicts caused by b/c conflicting with b+c, etc.

I have the following doubts regarding this :

a) "*A git pull at this point would result in chaos.*" - Why ? Since pull is non fast forward by default , won't the state become like this after the git fetch is executed. Where is the chaos ?

```
a---b---c---d---e---p---q---r (foo)
 \
  b+c---d+e---f  (origin/foo)
```

b) If a) is true , `git rebase origin/foo` will easily transform the graph as :

```
a
 \
  b+c---d+e---f  (origin/foo)
               \ 
                b---c---d---e---p---q---r (foo)
```

Where am I wrong ? Why he is saying `git fetch origin git rebase --onto origin/foo e foo`  will be executed ?

Comment: As a closing comment I will conclude : `git pull --rebase origin master` = `git fetch origin master` + `git rebase --onto origin/master $fork-point HEAD`. This `$fork-point` is given to rebase by git pull code

Answer (score 0):

You are correct regarding (a), but your conclusion (b) is wrong.

It is true that `git rebase` attempts to construct the history you depict in (b). But think how the changes `b` will look like when they are already part of upstream's `b+c`. If you are lucky, Git notice that they are and warns that the changeset is now empty. But in more typical cases, `b` conflicts with `b+c`. It is the same situation with the commits `c`, `d`, and `e`.

At the end (of a tedious series of conflict resolutions), you will find that all of `b`, `c`, `d`, and `e` should not have taken part in the rebase at all, and you can continue with the productive part. Finally, you arrive at the history that you actually want:

```
a
 \
  b+c---d+e---f  (origin/foo)
               \ 
                p---q---r (foo)
```

`git pull --rebase` saves you from this mess because it knows that your `p`, `q`, and `r` are the only commits that you want to rebase. Behind the scenes, it uses `git merge-base --fork-point` to find out that `e` was an upstream commit, i.e., not part of your branch.

Comment: I checked this behaviour of rebase removing redundant commits if they are squashed.Like here not taking b,c because of b+c. But results showed me that in case of squashed commits , git rebase command does not do it.  Did you also checked it once ?

Comment: Yes, I see this very often. `git rebase` cannot remove `b` automatically, because its changes are not exactly identical as any of the upstream. But sometimes Git can apply changes nevertheless: If the changes `b` are are completely independent from all of `c` to `f`, then Git can most likely apply `b` and notice that they were already applied. `git rebase` will stop and report something like _the commit is now empty._ It does not occur very often in practice, though.

Comment: Note: When and whether `git pull --rebase` or `git rebase` uses the fork-point code is a bit tricky. Assuming Git 2.18 helps since that eliminates a lot of "well, if your Git is versions X through Y, it behaves this way, but from Y through Z, it behaves this other way..."

Comment: @torek  I checked this behaviour in my git 2.18 and it resembles what author is saying. I am not aware how `git pull --rebase` uses fork-point or what actually is fork-point. If possible please post  an in depth answer for all of us. However , I know what git pull is and basic concept on what git rebase does.

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin: see the output of https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+fork-point