# compare changes after merging a forced push

Tags: git, version-control, rebase

Consider the 2nd scenario in [git pull --rebase lost commits after coworker's git push --force](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42536989/git-pull-rebase-lost-commits-after-coworkers-git-push-force) :

1. Dan and Brian start with a common commit.
2. Each makes a separate commit, so that the branch diverges.
3. Dan pushes first.
4. Brian force pushes without merging Dan's commit.
5. Dan pulls with `--rebase`, and observes his history lost.

In an online test, I was asked the following question.

> How can Dan compare the changes before and after the `git pull --rebase`?

I was required to respond with one single complete git command.

If I were actually working on my local repo, I would use `git reflog` to retrieve the appropriate commit IDs for `git diff`, but in the online test, I wasn't given such details.

---

Question source: online test on Codingame

> A 3rd-party user rebased accidentally and incorrectly, and then force pushed it.  You pulled these changes into your local repo and **lost all commit history**.
>
> What command can you execute to **list all changes** of the repo so that you can come back to a former state corresponding to a given reference?

[image: question source]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried inputting `git reflog` today, and the online test system accepted it.

`git reflog` is the command that retrieves the past git references that a user stayed, so that's the best response for the question.

[image]