# What checks does git perform to "force update" in a fetch? Is it something I can actually *see*?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-fetch

So let's assume I have the same repository in two different local directories, besides origin. Let's call these `localA/master` and `localB/master`. Both of them synchronized with an `origin/master`.

The log shows this in `localA/master` and `localB/master`:

```
7890858 (HEAD -> master, origin/master) Initial commit
```

Then I decide to change a file in `localA/master`, commit it and push it, then pull it in the branch of the other repo `localB/master`.

```
75b2345 (HEAD -> master, origin/master) Second commit
7890858 Initial commit
```

And now, in `localA/master` I hard-reset it back to 7890858 and force-push it.

```
 + 75b2345...7890858 master -> master (forced update)
```

```
7890858 (HEAD -> master, origin/master) Initial commit
```

I don't understand why when I do `git pull --rebase` in `localB/master`, the message is this:

```
 + 75b2345...7890858 master     -> origin/master  (forced update)
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/master.
```

which makes the branch go back to

```
7890858 (HEAD -> master, origin/master) Initial commit
```

I mean, I can recreate two situations where I'm working on a local branch with commits `A` and `B` and a remote branch with just `A`, and have different results for `git pull --rebase` depending on whether there was a forced update or not. There's the case I just described, and then the one where you have only `A` in remote and `A` and `B` in the local branch, except you committed `B` locally. The latter will tell you `Current branch master is up to date.`

What's going on here? How can git know if an update must be "forced"? How can I see that myself?

And how does rebase take that into consideration? In both cases I can get a virtually identical log (after `git pull`), looking like this:

```
9a5cb91 (HEAD -> master) Second commit, maybe force-pushed
7890858 (origin/master) Initial commit
```

Yet I can get two different results.

Comment: Here is an extensive answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42536989/git-pull-rebase-lost-commits-after-coworkers-git-push-force

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git pull --rebase lost commits after coworker's git push --force](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42536989/git-pull-rebase-lost-commits-after-coworkers-git-push-force)