# How can a new file be owerwritten at a git rebase?

Tags: git

So I had been working on a checkout out feature branch, let's call it `feature-branch-development`. I ended up with a considerable amount of commits on this branch, 15 or so. When it was finally time for me to rebase the `master` branch into feature-branch-development it stopped midway complaining about a new file that I added on `feature-branch-development` and gave me an error saying something like `Your changes on this branch will be overwritten, please commit or stash them.` I had of course already commited everything and my working tree was clean. It was as if git "believed" the new file also existed on master. Noteworthy is also that I had no merge conflicts at this point.

I solved the issue by squashing all my commits on `feature-branch-development` and rebased `master` again.

My question therefore is why git acted like this? I have an intermediate knowledge of Git and I'm merely asking this question to level my amount of knowledge.

Comment: I ran into the same problem.  After reading your question I tried squashing my commits as you did and it fixed it for me as well, so thanks.

Comment: Oops, well that deleted a file that had been ignored by .gitignore . So beware.  I think that ignored file is what caused the conflict in the first place. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be easier to answer with a concrete example.  It's simple enough *in principle* though: `git rebase` means: *Copy commits, as if by `git cherry-pick`.*  It's the copy step that is failing here.

We start on branch *R* (for rebase) and pick some new target branch *T* (for Target).  We then identify some set of commits to copy: these are, for the most part, commits that are on *R* but not on *T*.  (In a bit of a white lie, [the `git rebase` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html) suggests that these are the commits listed by `git log T..R` or `git log T..HEAD`.  That's mostly true, except that there are three extra fiddles added, or maybe "subtracted" would be the word.)

Then, having listed the commit hashes to copy, Git does a detached-HEAD checkout of the target branch, so that the current (`HEAD`) commit is the same commit that branch *T* identifies.  Note that we're not *on* branch *T*, we're just on the same *commit*.  Now, for each commit whose hash ID we saved, Git effectively (and sometimes literally) runs `git cherry-pick <hash-id>`:

```
                    ....... HEAD
                    v
...--o--o--o--o--o--o   <-- T
            \
             A--B--C   <-- R
```

We run `git cherry-pick A` to copy commit `A`.  If we call the new copy `A'`, the result looks like this:

```
                      A'  <-- HEAD
                     /
...--o--o--o--o--o--o   <-- T
            \
             A--B--C   <-- R
```

Then we run `git cherry-pick B` to copy `B` to `B'`:

```
                      A'-B'  <-- HEAD
                     /
...--o--o--o--o--o--o   <-- T
            \
             A--B--C   <-- R
```

We repeat until we have all the commits copied, and then as the last step, Git "peels the branch label" `R` off the original chain and pastes it at the end of the copied chain:

```
                      A'-B'-C'  <-- R (HEAD)
                     /
...--o--o--o--o--o--o   <-- T
            \
             A--B--C   <-- (only in reflogs and ORIG_HEAD)
```

#### Conflicts and other problems

Each copy—each cherry-pick step—is done using Git's *merge machinery*, or what I call the "verb form" of *to merge* (as opposed to the noun or adjective form, *a merge* or a *merge commit*—`git merge` normally makes a *merge commit* after doing the verb form *to merge*, and we are just using the first half of this).  You get, e.g., an add/add conflict when you merge a commit that adds a new file with a change that also adds the same new file.

The most likely place to get such a conflict is when making copy `A'` from `A`, because the *merge base* of a cherry-pick operation is the parent commit of the commit being copied.  A merge operation—the *to merge* verb—compares this merge base with *two* commits.  In this case, the two commits are commit `A` itself, and the tip-most commit of branch *T*, i.e., the commit to which *T* points.  Let's call this `X`, and mark the merge base with `*`:

```
                      ? [merge in progress] HEAD
                     /
...--o--o--*--o--o--X   <-- T
            \
             A--B--C   <-- R
```

If both commits `A` and `X`, compared to `*`, add a file `path/to/file.txt`, you get an add/add conflict.  The cherry-pick stops, leaving a merge conflict in progress.  You must solve it and tell rebase to resume.

What if `A` adds `path/to/file.txt` and it's *not* in commit `X`?  Normally, that would be no problem: Git would just create the file and put it in the new commit.  There would be no add/add conflict at all, just a perfectly good copy `A'` (and we would go on and do the rest of the rebase).

But perhaps file `path/to/file.txt` *exists in the work-tree* for some reason (e.g., as an *untracked* file, and perhaps ignored as well).  In this case, Git can't just copy `path/to/file.txt` out of commit `A`, overwriting the work-tree version.  You get an error message here, just as for a regular merge conflict.  You must solve the problem and tell rebase to resume.

There are some additional cases here for files that are in the index/staging-area (and hence can be in various commits) but are marked `--assume-unchanged` or `--skip-worktree`.  In newer versions of Git, the precise error message identifies whether the file that "would be overwritten" is truly *untracked*, or marked like this.  (This might be true in older versions of Git as well but I do not remember off hand and have not checked.)  This is why a concrete example is better: there are several different causes for this particular problem.

#### For completeness: the subtractions I mentioned

These are also covered (somewhat) in the rebase documentation, but it's worth mentioning the commits `git rebase` deliberately *doesn't* copy:

- It *cannot* copy any merge.  When using `--preserve`, `git rebase` will *re-perform* merges to try to reconstruct them, but it cannot copy the original merges.  So normally it does not even try.
- It omits merges that have an upstream equivalent (e.g., those that have *already been* cherry-picked).  In the original diagram (with `T` and `R`), Git checks to see if [the `git patch-id` value](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-patch-id.html) for `A`, `B`, or `C` match the `git patch-id` value for any of the commits on `T` to the right of the merge base commit.  If so, Git drops the `A`, `B`, and/or `C` commits whose patch ID already occurs upstream.
- If used with `--fork-point`, the rebase code runs `git merge-base --fork-point` to attempt to find upstream commits that were deliberately dropped.  This usually works pretty well with remote-tracking branches, and usually works less well if you set your own local branches as the upstreams for your own branches.  Using `--fork-point` is the *default* when rebasing on the upstream using the automatic mechanisms, so one must be careful here.  See [Git rebase - commit select in fork-point mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42486141/1256452) for more.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: check for files you are ignoring in the new directory structure, either by `.gitignore` or, as @torek mentioned, through `--assume-unchanged`.

I ran into a very similar problem.  In my case, I had a file that was being ignored somewhere in the new directory structure.  Apparently .gitignore'd files live in the working tree, and that is what caused the conflict.  I squashed my commits in a new branch, and that successfully rebased onto master without conflicts.  Then I noticed a file was missing, and realized it was an ignored file.  That file is now completely gone.  Something about doing the squash got rid of it without warning.