# Git rebase when previous commit changed

Tags: git

I frequently find myself working on two different work tickets that are on different git branches, but one is dependent on another, like this:

```
* later-branch
|
* earlier-branch
|
* some prior commit
|
```

(Each is a single commit here because we are using gerrit, but this question might apply to multiple commits for each as well.)  The earlier branch may be going through review, and so I might have to go back and modify it at some point with a `git commit --amend`.  As must happen, this will fork the history:

```
* earlier-branch
|
|  * later-branch
|  |
|  * previous version of earlier-branch
| /
* some prior commit
|
```

At this point I want to rebase the `later-branch` on top of the new version of `earlier-branch`.  But if I just do a `git checkout later-branch` followed by a `git rebase earlier-branch`, it always gets conflicts, because (I think) it must first apply the `previous version of earlier-branch` commit to the most recent version of `earlier-branch`.

What I end up doing is `git checkout earlier-branch -b new-later-branch-name` followed by `git cherry-pick later-branch` and `git br -D later-branch`.  Which is a pain.  Can anyone suggest a better way to handle this?

Comment: It seems to me you'd only get into this situation by cherry-picking *previous version of earlier-branch* when creating *later-branch*; otherwise *previous version of earlier-branch* would be reachable from *earlier-branch* and would be excluded from the rebase by default.  So... why? You could have just checked out the *original* *earlier-branch* commit and used that as the starting point for *later-branch* ...

Comment: "It seems to me you'd only get into this situation by cherry-picking previous version of earlier-branch when creating later-branch"

I didn't.  `previous version of earlier-branch` didn't exist when later-branch was created (see top picture).  The second picture is what it looks like after I go back and commit-amend the earlier commit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see two easy ways to do this.

The first, best option is to use `git rebase` in interactive mode. To do this, you would do

```
git checkout later-branch
git rebase -i earlier-branch
```

In the screen that pops up, you would choose to `drop` the `previous version of earlier-branch`:

```
drop efb1c19 previous version of earlier-branch
pick a25ba16 later-branch

# Rebase 65f3afc..a25ba16 onto 65f3afc (2 commands)
#
# Commands:
# p, pick = use commit
# r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
# e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
# s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
# f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
# x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
# d, drop = remove commit
...
```

This will rebase `later-branch` on top of `earlier-branch`, providing the following tree:

```
* later-branch
|
* earlier-branch
|
|  * previous version of earlier-branch
| /
* some prior commit
|
```

Another option is to simply do a `git cherry-pick`. If you do:

```
git checkout earlier-branch
git cherry-pick later-branch
```

You'll get the following tree:

```
* earlier-branch -> cherry-picked commit 1
|
* earlier-branch -> amended commit 0, now commit 2
|
|  * later-branch -> commit 1
|  |
|  * previous version of earlier-branch -> commit 0
| /
* some prior commit
|
```

So, in effect, this will produce the result you want, but it will advance `earlier-branch` by one. If the branch names are important to you, you could rename and reset them accordingly.

Comment: The cherry-pick recommendation is much as I described in the original question, that's rather a pain, especially if I want to maintain branch names.  But the interactive-rebase-with-drop idea is a good one - I hadn't considered that.  Tried it, and it works.  Thanks!  (Gave you an upvote but as a stackoverflow noob it doesn't count yet.)

Answer (score 6):

Aside from interactive rebase (as in [houtanb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44946153/1256452)), there are two more ways to do this somewhat, or much, more automatically:

- using `git rebase --onto`, or
- using the "fork-point" code (in Git since Git version 2.0).

To use the latter, you can run `git rebase --fork-point earlier-branch` when on `later-branch`.

(You can instead set `earlier-branch` as the *upstream* for `later-branch`—presumably just temporarily, for the duration of the rebasing—and then just run `git rebase` when on `later-branch`.  The reason is that `--fork-point` is the *default* when using the automatic upstream mode, but must be *explicitly requested* when using an explicit `<upstream>` argument to `git rebase`.)

Unfortunately, the last is especially magical-seeming, especially to those new to Git.  Fortunately, your diagram has in it the seeds to understanding it—and with it, `git rebase --onto`.

#### Defining fork-point

Let's take what you drew above and turn it sideways, then turn it even a little a bit more.  This gives me some room to draw in the branch names.  I'll replace the `*`s for each commit with round `o` nodes or uppercase letters and numbers.  I'll add a third commit, `C`, to the later branch as well just for illustration.

```
:
 .
  \
   o
    \
     A1   <-- earlier-branch
      \
       B--C   <-- later-branch
```

Now you are forced, for whatever reason, to copy commit `A1` to new commit `A2`, and move the branch label `earlier-branch` to point to the new copy:

```
:
 .
  \
   o--A2  <-- earlier-branch
    \
     A1
      \
       B--C   <-- later-branch
```

If only Git would remember that commit `A1` exists because `earlier-branch` *used to* contain commit `A1`, we could tell Git: "when copying `later-branch`, drop any commits that are still on it now, but used to be on it only because of `earlier-branch`".

But Git *does* remember this, for 30 days at least, by default.  Git has *reflogs*—logs of what used to be stored in each *reference* (including both regular branches and Git's so-called *remote tracking branches*).  If we add the reflog information to the drawing, it looks like this:

```
:
 .
  \
   o--A2   <-- earlier-branch
    \
     A1    <-- [earlier-branch@{1}]
      \
       B--C   <-- later-branch
```

In fact, if for some reason you must copy `A2` to `A3`, the diagram just grows another reflog entry, renumbering the existing one:

```
:
 .   A3    <-- earlier-branch
  \ /
   o--A2   <-- [earlier-branch@{1}]
    \
     A1    <-- [earlier-branch@{2}]
      \
       B--C   <-- later-branch
```

What the fork-point code does is to scan the *reflog* for some other reference, such as `earlier-branch`, and find these commits (in this case `A1`—it actually finds both `A1` and `A2`, in the latter case, but then winnows it down to the `A1` that's on both branches; see also [Git rebase - commit select in fork-point mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42486141/1256452)).  It then runs `git rebase --onto` for you, as if you had manually run:

```
git rebase --onto earlier-branch hash-of-A1
```

which gets us into how the `--onto` argument works.

#### Regular rebase, without `--onto`

Normally, you would run `git rebase` with one argument, as in `git rebase branch-name`, or even no arguments at all.  With no arguments at all, `git rebase` uses the current branch's *upstream* setting.  With a *`branch-name`* argument, `git rebase` calls that argument `<upstream>`.  (As an odd side effect, this also—since Git version 2.0 anyway—automatically enables or disables the `--fork-point` option, requiring you to use an explicit `--no-fork-point` or `--fork-point` if you want the other mode.)

In any case, Git uses the `<upstream>`—selected automatically if you did not specify one—for *two* purposes.  One is to limit the set of commits that will be copied: Git will consider copying the set of commits listed by running:

```
git rev-list <upstream>..HEAD
```

To see them in a more friendly fashion, use `git log`, or my preferred method, `git log --oneline --decorate --graph`, instead of `git rev-list` here:

```
git log --oneline --decorate --graph earlier-branch..HEAD
```

Ideally, we would see commits `B` and `C` here, with `C` listed first (Git has to use `--reverse` to make sure it copies `B` first).  If you copied `A1` to `A2` and/or on to `A3`, though, and moved the branch `earlier-branch`, we will see all of `A1`, `B`, and `C`.  (Git excludes `A2` or `A3`—whichever `earlier-branch` points to—but they're not on the list anyway.  It then uses the excluded `A2` or `A3` to exclude the commits *before* `A1`, so that's why we don't see those.)

The other purpose for this `<upstream>` branch name (or commit hash) is to select *where the copies go*.  When we copy one or more commits, each copied commit has to go after some existing commit.  The `<upstream>` argument provides the ID of the commit that will be the parent of the first commit we copy.

Hence, running `git rebase earlier-branch` makes Git list commits `A1`, `B`, and `C`, in that order.  It then—using the "detached HEAD" mode—copies `A1` to go after `earlier-branch`:

```
:
 .       A1'  <-- HEAD
  \     /
   o--A2   <-- earlier-branch
    \
     A1    <-- [earlier-branch@{1}]
      \
       B--C   <-- later-branch
```

and then copies `B` to go after `A1'`:

```
:
 .       A1'--B'  <-- HEAD
  \     /
   o--A2   <-- earlier-branch
    \
     A1    <-- [earlier-branch@{1}]
      \
       B--C   <-- later-branch
```

Rebase then copies `C` to `C'` and moves the branch label, `later-branch`, to wherever `HEAD` winds up, re-attaching your HEAD in the process:

```
:
 .       A1'--B'--C'  <-- later-branch (HEAD)
  \     /
   o--A2   <-- earlier-branch
    \
     A1    <-- [earlier-branch@{1}]
      \
       B--C   <-- [later-branch@{1}]
```

The `--onto` argument lets you tell Git *where the copies go*.

#### Using `--onto` with `git rebase`

When you add `--onto`, you tell Git rebase where to put the copies.  This frees up the `<upstream>` argument so that it now specifies only what *not* to copy!  So now you are free to tell Git: "copy everything that's *after* commit `A1`" by writing:

```
git rebase --onto earlier-branch <hash-of-A1>
```

Git does its usual thing, listing the commits to be copied (`B` and `C`), detaching your HEAD from `later-branch`, copying the commits one at a time with the copies going after the tip of `earlier-branch`, and finally moving the name `later-branch` to reattach your HEAD.

This is exactly what we wanted, all done semi-automatically: we tell Git *not* to copy `A1` itself, so that it copies just `B` and `C`.

When we specify an upstream, as in `git rebase earlier-branch`, Git *disables* the fork-point mode.  If we explicitly *enable* it, Git will fish through the `earlier-branch` reflog.  As long as the reflog entry for commit `A1` has not yet expired, Git will discover that `A1` used to be on `earlier-branch` and will use `--onto` for us to discard it from the to-copy list.

***Note that there is a bit of danger here.***  What if we really *wanted* `A1` after all, e.g., what if we backed `earlier-branch` up over `A1` only because we realized `A1` did not belong on the other branch?  Git will still think we copied it to some other commit, and don't want it copied now, and will toss off the list.  Fortunately, you can always undo a rebase: rebase doesn't *discard* anything at all, it just *copies*.  It then updates a branch, which saves the previous value in the branch's reflog.  But fishing around through reflogs, trying to find one particular set of commits, in a twisty maze of commits that are all alike, is not a lot of fun—so it is wise to think a bit before running rebase, with or without `--fork-point`.

#### Side note

In a few (rare) cases Git you don't have to do anything (no fork point mode, no manual `--onto` separation, no `--interactive`).  Specifically, if the *patch itself* did not change at all, but only the *wording in the commit message* changed, Git will detect the already-copied commit and skip it.  This happens because `git rebase` actually uses the *symmetric difference* mode of `git rev-list` with the `--cherry-pick --right-only --no-merges` options.  That is, rather than:

```
git rev-list <upstream>..HEAD
```

Git actually runs:

```
git rev-list --cherry-pick --right-only --no-merges <upstream>...HEAD
```

(note the three dots).  I don't have time to go into any more detail here, though.