# git pull --rebase has merge conflicts within my own branch on a file that isn't edited outside my branch

Tags: git, merge

I have a branch I've been working on. `git status` shows that it is up to date.

I checked out master, which is "behind by 43 commits and can be fast-forwarded".

```
git merge --ff-only
```

Now master is up to date and I checked out my branch again. `git status` shows it is up to date still.

I now want to rebase to master:

```
git pull --rebase
```

But I end up with a stream of merge conflicts on a file that *only I've changed*. I tried fixing the merge conflict, but each `git rebase --continue` comes up with another conflict seeming to reply every change I made to it.

In fact **the problematic file was renamed** and the merge conflicts I get are on an old filename. I performed many commits over the past days making updates to the file and renaming it a few times. All were done in my branch. Each time I made updates I committed and pushed it to my branch.

I don't understand the reason for the merge conflicts. The file looks to be up-to-date in my branch. What could cause this to occur?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't understand the reason for the merge conflicts.

The problem appears to be that Git has mis-paired the renamed files.

> In fact **the problematic file was renamed** and the merge conflicts I get are on an old filename. I performed many commits over the past days making updates to the file and renaming it a few times. All were done in my branch. Each time I made updates I committed and pushed it to my branch.

#### This is about `git merge`, but it applies to `git rebase` as well

When Git is asked to merge two branch tips—or indeed any pair of commits (`HEAD`, the current branch, and some other branch tip commit or any other commit at all), Git will first use `git merge-base --all` to identify the merge base(s) between these two tip commits:

```
...--o--B--o--o--...--H   <-- branchA (HEAD)
         \
          o--o--...--T   <-- branchB
```

It does not matter how many times the file was renamed, nor on which branch(es).  What matters is what Git sees when it runs:

```
git diff --find-renames B H
git diff --find-renames B T
```

Any file that Git identifies as "the same" in commits `B` and `H`, or "the same" in commit `B` and `T`, is decreed to be "the same file", regardless of its actual path name in commits `B`, `H`, and `T`.

Whatever *changes* Git sees between `B` and `H` are "our" changes (`--ours`).  Whatever *changes* Git sees between `B` and `T` are "their" changes (`--theirs`).  Git now tries to combine these changes.  Where they overlap, Git complains of a merge conflict.

If Git is mis-identifying some path in `B` with the same or a different path in `H` or `T`, the diff between the version of the file that (Git thinks) is in `B` vs the version of that same file (with maybe different path name) is in `H` or `T` will not be a "good diff", and will clash badly with the other diff.  This will produce the merge conflicts you are seeing.

The possible solutions are:

- Rename the file again in a new commit added to `H` and/or `T` so that Git doesn't mis-identify the files.
- Use the `-X find-renames=<value>` extended option to `git merge` to change the similarity index, to affect which files Git thinks are "the same".
- Allow the merge conflict to happen, but then just construct the correct result by wiping out Git's attempt to merge the file(s), substituting in correct hand-merged file(s) instead.

Note that if some file in `B` exists with the *same name* in `H` or `T`, Git will (currently) *always* pair those two files up, even if they're not related.  For instance, suppose commit `B` had a file named `polish`, referring to the country Poland, and both commits `H` and `T` rename this to `polish-as-in-the-country` while *one* commit, either `H` or `T`, creates a *new* file named `polish` that refers to shoe polish.  Git  will identify `B`'s `polish` (country) with the new `polish` (shoe) because these are the *same name*.  Plain `git diff` can be told to break this association, but `git merge` cannot.

Renaming the shoe-polish file to `polish-as-in-the-shoes` will cause Git not to see a `polish` in both `B` and the one tip commit.  Now Git will search for a "best match", and find instead `polish-as-in-the-country` each time, and know that the *same* rename was performed in both branches.

#### A rebase is (like) repeated cherry-picks, and each cherry-pick is a merge

Running `git rebase <upstream>` or `git rebase --onto <target> <upstream>` tells Git to copy a series of commits.  The commits to copy are (essentially) [as the documentation says](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html) those shown by `git log <upstream>..HEAD`.<sup>1</sup>  The commit after which they get copied is the one given by `<target>`, or is `<upstream>` if you do not specify a `<target>`.

In any case, once Git has the list of commits to copy, it copies them as if by running `git cherry-pick` on each one.  (Depending on your particular `git rebase` command, this may *actually* run `git cherry-pick`, or it may simulate it through `git format-patch ... | git am -3`.  I have not yet constructed a good example to illustrate when these produce different results—but if you do get a merge conflict, it's because `git am -3` fell back to three-way merge, which has the same effect as using `git cherry-pick`.)

Annoyingly, while you *can* control merge results with `git merge` (by adding new commits, or supplying `-X` options), you have little to no control over each cherry-pick during a rebase.  The merge base of any cherry-pick is the parent commit of the commit being picked.  The `--theirs` commit is the commit being cherry-picked, and the `--ours` or `HEAD` commit is the commit being built-upon.  If the rebase is just starting, that's the `<target>` you gave, otherwise it's the commit most recently successfully copied.

In any case, at this point you're down to the one option: merge the file correctly by hand.  (Well, that or terminate the rebase attempt entirely, with `git rebase --abort`.  You could then use `git cherry-pick` yourself, repeatedly, and add `-X` arguments if appropriate.)

---

<sup>1</sup>The documentation has a white lie here.  It's *almost* those commits that Git copies; it is *actually* those listed by `git rev-list --cherry-pick --right-only --no-merges <upstream>...HEAD`.  This is the same list, except that it:

- omits any merge commits, and
- omits any commit that has the same [`git patch-id`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-patch-id.html) in the upstream target.

Moreover, as is actually documented, `--fork-point` changes the starting point from the given `<upstream>` argument in some cases, so as to omit even more commits.  See [Git rebase - commit select in fork-point mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42486141/1256452).

Comment: A phenomenal explanation! This has made a measurable improvement in my understanding of Git. Thanks for going to the effort here!

Comment: I forgot to add: `git rebase` works much as if by `git cherry-pick`ing each commit, and you have no control over which commits are base, HEAD/ours, and theirs, so when things go wrong during `git rebase` it's even more painful than when they go wrong during `git merge`.