# Git: How to check if any commits were deleted?

Tags: git, git-pull, git-fetch

I want to ensure that no commits are deleted (or squashed) from my local repository by `fetch` from a remote repository.

Also I need to reveal to me, if any commits were deleted (or squashed) at the remote repository.

How can I make sure that my `fetch` or `pull` does not delete any commits (on my local PC)?

Another related question: How to make Git to delete local commits corresponding to deleted remote commits?

Comment: Git will only delete unreachable commits. Maybe there’s a command for that?

Comment: fetch or pull will never squash/delete commits. They will make merge commits when your histories have diverged because somebody altered a sequence of commits, usually with gross results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some problems with this question, and maybe that's why it got down-voted, but we *can* make something out of it.

Let's take a look at what's actually stored in a Git repository, drawn as a graph, before and after `git fetch`, to see what I mean.

We'll start with this:

```
          A   <-- master
         /
...--o--*   <-- origin/master
         \
          B--C   <-- origin/dev
```

Here, in the local repository, before running `git fetch origin`, we have:

- some number of shared commits, starting with commit `*` and working backwards;
- one commit that is "ours", commit `A`, on our `master`, that is not on `origin/master`
- two commits that are the upstream's only, on their `dev` which is our `origin/dev`: commits `B` and `C`.

Now we run `git fetch`, which prints some output, which for some reason we don't see or have forgotten.  We then inspect our graph carefully again and discover this:

```
          A   <-- master
         /
...--o--*--D   <-- origin/master
            \
             E   <-- origin/dev
```

That is, the two commits I labeled `B` and `C` are no longer reachable at all, from any of the `origin/*` names, while new commits `D` and `E` have appeared.  The name `origin/master`, which is our Git's memory of their `master`, now identifies commit `D`, while the name `origin/dev` identifies commit `E`.

It's reasonably likely—but impossible to tell for sure from this amnesiac view—that commit `D` is the result of squashing commits `B` and `C`, and possibly some additional commits that we never had.  Commit `E` is probably entirely new.  On the other hand, we just don't know.

We probably have more information than this, though.  In particular, if we have reflogs enabled, we will have `origin/master@{1}` and `origin/dev@{1}`.  These will point to commits `*` and `C` respectively, and we'll retain both `C` and `B` through the `origin/master@{1}` reflog.

We might also have a different starting picture.  For instance, maybe our starting image looks like this instead:

```
          A   <-- master
         /
...--o--*   <-- origin/master
         \
          B--C   <-- dev, origin/dev
```

In this case our ending picture looks like this:

```
          A   <-- master
         /
...--o--*--D   <-- origin/master
         \  \
          \  E   <-- origin/dev
           \
            B--C   <-- dev
```

#### What to know

There are several things to note here:

1. We never lose any commits to which our own branch names point.
2. We never update any of our own branch names at all.
3. We do update our remote-tracking names, but when we do, if reflogs are enabled, their *previous* values get saved in our reflogs for those names.

Hence:

> I want to ensure that no commits are deleted (or squashed) from my local repository by fetch from a remote repository.

This is just automatically true, if by "no commits" you mean "no commits to which I have names other than remote-tracking names".

> Also I need to reveal to me, if any commits were deleted (or squashed) at the remote repository.

Here, you can look at the difference between any updated remote-tracking names—note that `git fetch` tells you which names it is updating—and their saved reflog values.  If, for instance, `origin/master` and `origin/dev` were updated, you can compare `origin/master@{1}` with `origin/master`.

At this point, several of the special [syntaxes](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65541/plural-of-syntax) described in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) become quite handy.  In particular the two-dot and three-dot set-difference and symmetric-difference operators tell us just what we want to know:

```
git rev-list origin/master@{1}..origin/master
```

produces the list of commits *added to* `origin/master`, and:

```
git rev-list origin/master..origin/master@{1}
```

produces the list of commits *removed from* origin/master.  We still have all of those commits in our repository since the reflog names point to them; they won't vanish until the reflog entries expire.

We can use the three-dot syntax along with `--left-right`, or similar entities, to enumerate and identify commits added and removed, marking which "side" of the symmetric difference they are on:

```
git rev-list --left-right origin/master@{1}...origin/master
```

Using all of this information we can automatically guess, if we really care, which commits might be rebases or squashes of which other commits, but this is a doomed effort in some cases (e.g., resolved merge conflicts).

> Another related question: How to make Git to delete local commits corresponding to deleted remote commits?

This is trickier as it depends on what you mean.  However, if you mean what I am guessing you mean, the `--fork-point` operation of `git rebase` is actually designed to handle this.  The fork-point code uses the reflog of the upstream branch.  For details, see [Git rebase - commit select in fork-point mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42486141/git-rebase-commit-select-in-fork-point-mode).