# Can I rebase on a branch's fork point without explicitly specifying the parent?

Tags: git

I often use `git rebase -i` to clean up my history before publishing it. Usually I want to edit commits back to wherever the current branch forked off, without changing its fork point. I do it something like this: `git rebase -i $(git show-branch --merge-base $PARENT_BRANCH HEAD)`

It's an ugly command and I'm trying to find a better way. As long as I'm at it, I'd like to have git automatically figure out the right parent.

I *think* what I want is an alias for `git rebase -i --fork-point $(something)`, where `something` finds the branch with the most recent common ancestor of the current branch. It doesn't need to be bulletproof. If it works for a linear topic branch, that's good enough for my purposes.

Comment: If you want to squash everything back to the merge-base:  git reset --soft $(git merge-base HEAD @{u}); git commit -m 'squash!'

Comment: Squash or no squash, I suspect "git merge-base HEAD @{u}" would be helpful here...

Comment: With Git 2.24 (Q4 2019), you would do `git rebase --keep-base <upstream>` instead. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58252582/6309).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With Git 2.24 (Q4 2019), no more `git rebase -i --onto @{upstream}...HEAD`

The new "`git rebase --keep-base <upstream>`" tries to find the original base of the topic being rebased and **rebase on top of that same base**, which is useful when running the "`git rebase -i`" (and its limited variant "`git rebase -x`").

The command also has learned to fast-forward in more cases where it can instead of replaying to recreate identical commits.

See [commit 414d924](https://github.com/git/git/commit/414d924beb41b9f39744b5574231856d5ffbcba8), [commit 4effc5b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4effc5bc96ab8cd057e034c11d6f4b93b49cb0a3), [commit c0efb4c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c0efb4c1ddccf91dedd5775f2f449574e90b051a), [commit 2b318aa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2b318aa6c3566ad65d9547f42828f277955e6519) (27 Aug 2019), and [commit 793ac7e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/793ac7e309437e2225825370a9c7a0f1ccb39480), [commit 359eceb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/359ecebc346eeb3c74af82f25d8fce94d3ce35a4) (25 Aug 2019) by [Denton Liu (`Denton-L`)](https://github.com/Denton-L).
Helped-by: [Eric Sunshine (`sunshineco`)](https://github.com/sunshineco), [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster), [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar), and [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
See [commit 6330209](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6330209d7d34f72e2e1511f7e42e267b926ff64d), [commit c9efc21](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c9efc216830fa2fb71e7d917294e4530a33a4da1) (27 Aug 2019), and [commit 4336d36](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4336d365123e45be0ed4a7286df54ccce560d55f) (25 Aug 2019) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
Helped-by: [Eric Sunshine (`sunshineco`)](https://github.com/sunshineco), [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster), [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar), and [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 640f9cd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/640f9cd5994ed2061405aa94972b1746bb0c393e), 30 Sep 2019)</sup>

> ### rebase: teach rebase `--keep-base`

> A common scenario is if a user is working on a topic branch and they wish to make some changes to intermediate commits or autosquash, they would run something such as
>
> ```
> git rebase -i --onto master... master
> ```
>
> **in order to preserve the merge base**.
> This is useful when contributing a patch series to the Git mailing list, one often starts on top of the current '`master`'.
> While developing the patches, '`master`' is also developed further and it is sometimes not the best idea to keep rebasing on top of 'master', but to keep the base commit as-is.
>
> In addition to this, a user wishing to test individual commits in a topic branch without changing anything may run
>
> ```
> git rebase -x ./test.sh master... master
> ```
>
> Since rebasing onto the merge base of the branch and the upstream is such a common case, introduce the `--keep-base` option as a shortcut.
>
> This allows us to rewrite the above as
>
> ```
> git rebase -i --keep-base master
> ```
>
> and:
>
> ```
> git rebase -x ./test.sh --keep-base master
> ```
>
> respectively.

[`git rebase` man page now includes](https://github.com/git/git/blob/414d924beb41b9f39744b5574231856d5ffbcba8/Documentation/git-rebase.txt#L220-L234):

> ### `--keep-base`:

> Set the starting point at which to create the new commits to the merge base of `<upstream> <branch>`.
> Running '`git rebase --keep-base <upstream> <branch>`' is equivalent to running '`git rebase --onto <upstream>... <upstream>`'.
>
> This option is useful in the case where one is developing a feature on top of an upstream branch.
> While the feature is being worked on, the upstream branch may advance and it may not be the best idea to keep rebasing on top of the upstream but to keep the base commit as-is.
>
> Although both this option and `--fork-point` find the merge base between
> `<upstream> and <branch>`, this option uses the merge base as the *starting point* on which new commits will be created, whereas `--fork-point` uses the merge base to determine the *set of commits* which will be rebased.

---

[mvds](https://stackoverflow.com/users/371793/mvds) suggests [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53234798/can-i-rebase-on-a-branchs-fork-point-without-explicitly-specifying-the-parent/58252582#comment113169297_58252582) combining this with [`git rebase --reapply-cherry-picks`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---reapply-cherry-picks)

> In my workflow, to develop a minimal binary patch for firmware written in C, I need to go back to a certain commit hash, make a branch, perform modifications and find differences in the resulting binary.
>
> In the time since that certain commit, our compiler was upgraded and became smarter, turning the codebase into non-compiling code.
>
> To remedy this, I cherry-pick any commits needed to be able to compile again.
> Those cherry-picked commits will mess up the magic done by `--keep-base`, unless `--reapply-cherry-picks` is used.

The [debate is on the Git mailing-list](https://public-inbox.org/git/0EA8C067-5805-40A7-857A-55C2633B8570@gmail.com/T/#u)

---

Before Git 2.39 (Q4 2022), "[`git rebase --keep-base`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/003f815dd9f42b1bb893338b32d9cce33a8926c1/Documentation/git-rebase.txt#L216)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---keep-base))</sup> used to discard the commits that are already cherry-picked to the upstream, even when "keep-base" meant that the base, on top of which the history is being rebuilt, does not yet include these cherry-picked commits.
The `--keep-base` option now implies `--reapply-cherry-picks` and `--no-fork-point` options.

See [commit aa1df81](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aa1df8146d70bb85c63b0999868fe29aebc1173e), [commit ce5238a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ce5238a690821d1de230091dd6c9c13a99ed6752), [commit d42c9ff](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d42c9ffa0fa169ea51c971d1143b3f20d5a32d83), [commit a770602](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a77060218dfae5e8209a0ee131f292b881ce533b), [commit f21becd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f21becdd94d17ae792b951cf784898324bedfda5), [commit b8dbfd0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b8dbfd030ccc8e5be6b22bc28a342119504e0c2b), [commit 05ec418](https://github.com/git/git/commit/05ec41855da2ba813e6cfb5fb1fb86aea623addc), [commit 96601a2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/96601a26b4cdb2184b79b63aa670f695f5690183) (17 Oct 2022) by [Phillip Wood (`phillipwood`)](https://github.com/phillipwood).
<sup>(Merged by [Taylor Blau -- `ttaylorr` --](https://github.com/ttaylorr) in [commit 003f815](https://github.com/git/git/commit/003f815dd9f42b1bb893338b32d9cce33a8926c1), 30 Oct 2022)</sup>

> ### [`rebase --keep-base`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aa1df8146d70bb85c63b0999868fe29aebc1173e): imply `--no-fork-point`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Phillip Wood</sup>

> Given the name of the option it is confusing if `--keep-base` actually changes the base of the branch without `--fork-point` being explicitly given on the command line.
>
> The combination of `--keep-base` with an explicit `--fork-point` is still supported even though `--fork-point` means we do not keep the same base if the upstream branch has been rewound.
> We do this in case anyone is relying on this behavior which is [tested in `t3431`](https://lore.kernel.org/git/20200715032014.GA10818@generichostname/

`git rebase` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/aa1df8146d70bb85c63b0999868fe29aebc1173e/Documentation/git-rebase.txt#L221):

> `git rebase --reapply-cherry-picks --no-fork-point --onto <upstream>...<branch> <upstream> <branch>`.

`git rebase` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/aa1df8146d70bb85c63b0999868fe29aebc1173e/Documentation/git-rebase.txt#L455-L457):

> If `<upstream>` or `--keep-base` is given on the command line, then
> the default is `--no-fork-point`, otherwise the default is
> `--fork-point`. See also `rebase.forkpoint` in [`git config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config).

And still with Git 2.39:

> ### [`rebase --keep-base`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ce5238a690821d1de230091dd6c9c13a99ed6752): imply `--reapply-cherry-picks`
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Philippe Blain</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Phillip Wood</sup>

> As `--keep-base` does not rebase the branch it is confusing if it removes commits that have been cherry-picked to the upstream branch.
> As `--reapply-cherry-picks` is not supported by the "apply" backend this commit ensures that cherry-picks are reapplied by forcing the upstream commit to match the onto commit unless `--no-reapply-cherry-picks` is given.

`git rebase` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ce5238a690821d1de230091dd6c9c13a99ed6752/Documentation/git-rebase.txt#L226-L228):

> rebasing on top of the upstream but to keep the base commit as-is. As
> the base commit is unchanged this option implies `--reapply-cherry-picks`
> to avoid losing commits.

`git rebase` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ce5238a690821d1de230091dd6c9c13a99ed6752/Documentation/git-rebase.txt#L317-L326):

> In the absence of `--keep-base` (or if `--no-reapply-cherry-picks` is
> given), these commits will be automatically dropped.
>
> Because this
> necessitates reading all upstream commits, this can be expensive in
> repositories with a large number of upstream commits that need to be
> read.
> When using the 'merge' backend, warnings will be issued for each
> dropped commit (unless `--quiet` is given). Advice will also be issued
> unless `advice.skippedCherryPicks` is set to false (see
> [`git config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config)).

Comment: I don't have 2.24 yet (I stick to what's in APT, and it's not in the repos), but this feature is exactly what I was looking for so I'm accepting it anyway.

Comment: I would like to add that --reapply-cherry-picks may be of use: In my workflow, to develop a minimal binary patch for firmware written in C, I need to go back to a certain commit hash, make a branch, perform modifications and find differences in the resulting binary. In the time since that certain commit, our compiler was upgraded and became smarter, turning the codebase into non-compiling code. To remedy this, I cherry-pick any commits needed to be able to compile again. Those cherry-picked commits will mess up the magic done by --keep-base, unless --reapply-cherry-picks is used!

Comment: @mvds Excellent point, thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Apparently it is a point of discussion whether --keep-base should imply --reapply-cherry-picks: https://public-inbox.org/git/0EA8C067-5805-40A7-857A-55C2633B8570@gmail.com/

Answer (score 4):

First, `--fork-point` is meant for remote-tracking names.  The way it works is that it uses the reflog for the supplied upstream.  For more about this, see, e.g., [Git rebase - commit select in fork-point mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42486141/1256452).

Second—but maybe more important—you can run `git rebase upstream`, `git rebase --onto newbase upstream`, or even just `git rebase`.  When using the two argument form, you gain a lot of freedom:

- The *`upstream`* argument limits which commits are going to be copied.  We'll have more to say about this in a moment.
- The *`newbase`* argument chooses which commit is the point after which the copies are to be added.  The actual hash ID here is very important.

That is, when you *do* use `--onto`, you must pick an exact commit for the `--onto` *`newbase`* argument.  This means you can be very loose about what you use as the *`upstream`* argument.  But when you *don't* use `--onto`, *`upstream`* gets used for *both purposes*, so the *`upstream`* parameter is the one that requires a lot of careful preciseness.  One purpose is loose and free, and the other isn't.

What this means that you can use *two* arguments to regain any extra looseness you'd like (but may not need), or *no* arguments to gain convenience.

(The next part is constructed oddly due to an update to the question.)

#### `git show-branch --merge-base X Y` = `git merge-base X Y`

The `git show-branch` command now takes `--merge-base` or `--independent` when given multiple arguments.  With exactly two arguments, it does the same thing as `git merge-base X Y`, i.e., it finds the merge base(s) of revisions `X` and `Y`.  (`git merge-base` also now takes `--independent`, rather than just assuming the octopus strategy, but this only applies when using three or more commit specifiers.)

I prefer `git merge-base` here, as I think it's more obvious (and of course a little shorter to type in).

#### With no arguments, the *upstream* comes from your branch settings

Every branch can have one (but only one) upstream setting.

The upstream setting of any branch *B* is usually `origin/B`, because we tend to push them to GitHub or Bitbucket or some corporate web server, whose URL we stick under the name `origin` so that we don't have to type it out all the time.  If you've used up your one upstream on `origin/`, and want to have a *second* setting that `git rebase` will use automatically, you're sort of out of luck (but read on).  But if you *haven't* used up the one upstream, just set the upstream to what you'd like `git rebase` to use automatically.  For instance, if you're on `feature-X` now and want it to rebase on `develop`:

```
$ git branch --set-upstream-to=develop
```

and now `feature` has `develop` as its one upstream.  Running `git rebase` (with or without `-i`) will rebase as if you ran the same command with `develop` as its *`upstream`* argument.

If you have used up the one upstream, you can make your own alias:

```
alias.name = !git rebase "$@" $(git config --get branch.$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD).base) #
```

(pick some name): this lets you configure, using `git config`, an extra name, `branch.feature-X.base`, to `develop`.  The `$(git symbolic-ref --short)` extracts the current branch name, the `git config --get` gets the setting, and the rebase then uses that as its one upstream argument.

#### The drawback to a single limiter-and-target / newbase argument

The drawback here is that, given a graph of the form:

```
             o--o   <-- develop
            /
...--o--o--o
            \
             A--B--C   <-- feature-X (HEAD)
```

you wind up with copies that come after the tip of `develop`:

```
                  A'-B'-C'  <-- feature-X (HEAD)
                 /
             o--o   <-- develop
            /
...--o--o--o
            \
             A--B--C   [abandoned]
```

when you want to keep the copies in the same place, just fuss with their commit text or maybe squash two together or something:

```
             o--o   <-- develop
            /
...--o--o--o--A'-B'-C'  <-- feature-X (HEAD)
            \
             A--B--C   [abandoned]
```

#### Using `--onto`

With the two-argument form, the `--onto` parameter picks the target commit:

```
             o--o   <-- develop or whatever
            /
...--o--o--*    [pick this commit as target]
            \
             A--B--C   <-- feature-X (HEAD)
```

The copies will now go after `*`.  The set of commits to be copied is determined by using, in effect, `upstream..feature-X`: that is, the commits reachable by starting at `feature-X` and working backwards, but excluding commits reachable by starting at *`upstream`* and working backwards.

Now you need only find commit `*`.  If you have two names, such as `feature-X` and `develop`, you can use the [gitrevisions three-dot syntax](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html), `develop...feature-X` or `feature-X...develop` (the syntax is symmetric when there is only one merge base like this), to specify commit `*`.  This only works in fairly new versions of Git: in older ones, use `git show-branch` or `git merge-base` (with two commit hash IDs they both behave the same way).

Having specified commit `*` as the `--onto` target, you can again allow the branch's upstream to work as the limiter.  That is, you can omit the explicit *`upstream`* because it defaults to the actual upstream.  And, since you can use the `@{upstream}` or `@{u}` syntax, you can make a very short and simple alias, as you did in your own answer.

If you want to keep a separate upstream (`origin/feature-X`) and base, you can go back to the idea of configuring an extra value per branch name.  In this case, you'll need to use it twice, so instead of an alias, you might want a full blown script, where you can do error checking:

```
#! /bin/sh
# git-base - rebase on the current branch's base setting
. git-sh-setup
branch=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD) || exit
base=$(git config --get branch.$branch.base) || die "branch.$branch.base is not set"
mbase=$(git merge-base $base HEAD) || die "there is no merge base"
git rebase --onto $mbase "$@" $base
```

Name this `git-base`, put it in your path, and you can now run `git base`.

Comment: "it may be the case that you aren't actually using a parent branch name here, or are running git show-branch --merge-base HEAD $PARENT_BRANCH." It probably varies, honestly, depending on whether I remember the HEAD part on any given day. Fixed that line in the question so it actually makes sense.

Comment: I'm not sure which answer to mark as accepted. Mine concisely answers exactly the question I asked, but yours is much more informative in general. Is there established etiquette on this?

Comment: Might as well take your own, I guess. I'm not sure what if anything is standard here.

Comment: Okay, done. But I added a link to yours for a more detailed explanation of the mechanics behind the solution.

Answer (score 2):

After plugging at this for an hour or so, I came up with something good-enough. This command does what I want *if* the branch has an upstream set, and if said upstream is the one I want to compare against:

```
$ git rebase -i --onto @{upstream}...HEAD
```

Those triple dots do not do the same thing as in git-log and similar commands. From the [git-rebase documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase):

> As a special case, you may use "A...B" as a shortcut for the merge base of
>   A and B if there is exactly one merge base.

So this is saying "find the merge-base of HEAD and its own upstream, and rebase against that". Normally local branches have no upstream, but it can be set, and there is a gitconfig option (autoSetupMerge) that will do it automatically for new branches. Hence:

```
$ git config --global branch.autoSetupMerge always
$ git config --global alias.fixup 'rebase -i --onto @{upstream}...HEAD'
$ git branch childbranch -u parentbranch  # Repeat for other branches as needed.
```

After this I can edit history back to the branch point easily with:

```
git fixup
```

And it works for all future branches.

(note: See [torek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53235508/4638839) for a detailed explanation of what's going on under the hood here)

Comment: Using `--onto` is probably the way to go.  I've been working on a long-form answer. That three-dot syntax is the correct syntax for specifying the (well, *a*) merge base; see [gitrevisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).

Comment: Can you quote where gitrevisions says that? All the references I can find to triple-dots use it to mean roughly "the set of commits going back to the merge-base" not "the merge-base commit itself". I was surprised to find that it worked that way with --onto.

Comment: It's a little sneaky, because A...B really is a range syntax for anything that uses ranges. The trick is that Git commands that want a single number pass that to `git rev-parse` (or the C code equivalent), which spits out the two end points as positive references and the merge base(s) as negative references. `git diff` and, in modern Git, `git rebase`, know how to handle that.

Comment: In this particular case, if you examine the old shell-script rebase setup code, it [explicitly checks for the three-dot syntax and runs `git merge-base`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8858448bb49332d353febc078ce4a3abcc962efe/git-legacy-rebase.sh#L580). The new code [is very similar](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8858448bb49332d353febc078ce4a3abcc962efe/builtin/rebase.c#L1275).